# Selecting result from two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, select

I have the following tables.

**Terminal:**

[image]

**Outlet:**

[image]

**vpos_out:**

[image]

When I execute the following query, everything looks good:

```
SELECT TOP 2
    o.id,
    mt.id AS [activated_device],
    vo.id AS [outlet]
FROM 
    terminalmt WITH (NOLOCK) 
LEFT JOIN 
    outlet o WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.id = mt.outlet_id AND  mt.status = 0
LEFT JOIN 
    vpos_out vo WITH (NOLOCK) ON vo.wallet_id = o.wallet_id AND vo.status = 1
WHERE 
    o.wallet_id = 356988
```

I get the following result:

[image]

The problem is when I change the mt.status value to 12 ( a status that clearly doesn't exist.

In this case I don't get any results.

I want to get the following result

[image]

Any ideas ?

Comment: Your where clause is turning your left join into an inner join. Also, be careful splattering NOLOCK everywhere. It is not a magic go faster button without any side affects. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Why are you joining on wallet_id? It's not unique for any of the tables in the join.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need (note the extra term in the where clause):

```
    SELECT
      TOP 2
      o.id,
     mt.id as [activated_device],
     vo.id as [outlet]
      FROM terminalmt WITH(NOLOCK) 
      LEFT JOIN outlet o WITH(NOLOCK) ON o.id = mt.outlet_id AND  mt.status = 0
      LEFT JOIN vpos_out vo WITH(NOLOCK) ON vo.wallet_id = o.wallet_id AND vo.status = 1
    WHERE o.wallet_id = 356988 OR o.id is NULL
```

To handle where there is no row on the other side of the join to the outlet table.

Comment: Or even easier would be to move the o.wallet_id predicate to the join. :)

Comment: I don't think that this works correctly. There are records where there is a value for outlet. I want a number to be shown in the oultet column if there is any value, not NULL .

Comment: I think you need to share more detail then. With no table structure or sample data we're all just guessing at things like if the wallet_id column is nullable (I was assuming it wasn't). 

I don't think your logic works though. In your sample query there has to be a value for wallet_id and therefore there has to be one for the id on the same table.

Answer (score 0):

Since you always want `outlet` records, and the rest is optional depending on filtering, you need to start with the `outlet` table and then `left join` the rest onto that.

Like this:

```
SELECT TOP 2
    o.id,
    mt.id AS [activated_device],
    vo.id AS [outlet]
FROM 
    outlet o WITH (NOLOCK) 
LEFT JOIN 
    terminal mt WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.id = mt.outlet_id AND mt.status = 12
LEFT JOIN 
    vpos_out vo WITH (NOLOCK) ON vo.wallet_id = o.wallet_id AND vo.status = 1
WHERE 
    o.wallet_id = 356988
```

And I agree with the comment that was made about plastering `WITH (NOLOCK)` on all tables. It mostly means that you *don't care about accuracy and correctness of the results*. You should think twice (or thrice) before using it.